# how can i change the code for tensorflow 0.12 version

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I have a code, which was running before but not now.

```
# ## Create a regressor with TF Learn
# **Parameters**:
# - model_fn: regression model
# - n_classes: 0 for regression
# - verbose
# - steps: training steps
# - optimizer: ("SGD", "Adam", "Adagrad")
# - learning_rate
# - batch_size
    regressor = learn.TensorFlowEstimator(model_fn=lstm_model(TIMESTEPS, RNN_LAYERS, DENSE_LAYERS),n_classes=0,verbose=1,steps=TRAINING_STEPS,optimizer='Adagrad',learning_rate=0.03,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

But now I'm getting error which says `"AttributeError: 'tensorflow.contrib.learn' object has no attribute 'TensorFlowEstimator'"`

How can I modify this instruction for Tensorflow 0.12?

Comment: Is tensorflow.contrib.learn.TensorFlowEstimate not used in the new version? Is it instead by tensorflow.contrib.learn.Estimate ? How can I modify this instruction? Thanks. I am a novice studying tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `TensorFlowEstimator` with `Estimator`. There has been a significant re-factor in 0.12, please have a look at the [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.learn/estimators) docs.

Comment: Could you help to modify the code with BaseEstimator or Estimator?